# karaf 3 with OSGi , how install a bundle

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, apache-karaf, karaf

How create a bundle using `Apache karaf 3`?  Someone know ?

I have try in `Eclipse`:
I export a jar with a manifest file ... and why I have this error:

```
karaf@root(dev)> feature:repo-add file:///C:/Users/xx/Downloads/apache-kara
f-3.0.1/apache-karaf-3.0.1/deploy/features.xml
Adding feature url file:///C:/Users/xx/Downloads/apache-karaf-3.0.1/apache-
karaf-3.0.1/deploy/features.xml
karaf@root(dev)> feature:install greeter_server
Error executing command: Jar is not a bundle, no Bundle-SymbolicName file:///C:/
Users/xx/Downloads/apache-karaf-3.0.1/apache-karaf-3.0.1/deploy/nebula_cdat
etime_VF4.jar
karaf@root(dev)>
```

This is my `features.xml`:

```
<features>
<feature name='greeter_server' version='1.0'>
<bundle>file:///C:/Users/xx/Downloads/apache-karaf-3.0.1/apache-karaf-3.0.1/deploy/nebula_cdatetime_VF4.jar</bundle>
</feature>
</features>
```

Comment: Which tutorials or documentation did you read before starting?

Comment: I have done this tutorial : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/OSGi/article.html
and  this tutorial : http://www.eclipsetotale.com/articles/Developpement_de_plugins_Eclipse_partie1.html

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Please re-read section 2 of Lars' tutorial. It details how bundles differ from plain JARs.

Comment: Looks like you haven't made any efforts to trouble shoot the issue. Anyone remotely familiar with OSGi knows they need to assign a value to Bundle-SymbolicName attribute in the jar manifest file. Your jar manifest file is  probably doesn't have it declared. It may help to make your build tool whether ant/maven/gradle generate the manifest of your jar.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to export a bundle or a declarative service from [eclipse rcp](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Rich_Client_Platform) you must use the ***file -> export -> plugin development-> deployable plugins and fragments*** as explained [here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/export_wizards/export_plugins.htm).

Obviously the project you want to export as a bundle must have a sound manifest file. To have an idea of a correct osgi-friendly structure your project should have, you could create a test plugin project in eclipse rcp using the *File → New → Other... → Plug-in Development → Plug-in Project* menu. In the wizard you can choose to create a simple osgi bundle with an activator. The outcome is a skeleton for your new osgi bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I think an easier and cleaner way is to use Maven. This way you can produce a correct OSGI ready JAR which may be loaded quickly into Karaf.
In this case pom.xml file should be like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>your.group
  <artifactId>artifact-123</artifactId>
  <name>Karaf OSGI Module</name>
  <packaging>bundle</packaging>
  ....
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <instructions />
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

This kind of POM file will produce a JAR which is OSGI compatible and you don't have to mess up with absolute file names. In your feature.xml we can declare the module like this:

```
<bundle>mvn:your.group/artifact-123/${pom.version}</bundle>
```